# How to detect TCP connection failure using NetworkStream.DataAvailable property?

Tags: c#, .net, tcplistener

When using `Socket` for TCP, trying to read data when the connection has been lost will throw an exception. 
I'm used to using exceptions to be aware when a TCP operation fails, since you cannot reliably tell a connection is broken except by trying to read/write.

But I just noticed that `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` simply returns `false` in this case, and `TcpClient.GetStream` also returns successfully. I have code like the following (used in a poll-loop) - is there a way to expand this approach to detect failed connections?

```
    public int Read()
    {
        var stream = tcp.GetStream();
        if (!stream.DataAvailable)
            return 0;
        else
            return stream.Read(InBuffer, 0, InBuffer.Length);
    }
```

If not then I would have to call one of the `Read` methods using a timeout - which makes me wonder what is the point of `DataAvailable` as it would easily lead to bugs where failed connections are not detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

See, you get an exception when the connection is broken.

DataAvailable may simply not have data available AT THE MOMENT. Packets take time to travel and packets may get lost. TCP is having a mechnism to resend list packets, but it causes a delay.

GetStream returns the stream. This is your endpoint. It returns it when the connection is available, which makes sense. DataAvailable is there to check whether there is data waiting. Data not waiting is NOT a lost connection - it is data not waiting.

Comment: Yes this makes sense... but it makes `DataAvailable` seem kind of dangerous. If you are waiting for data before reading it, and the connection is lost, you'd never know. On the other hand if you try to `Read` data which _will_ cause an exception, what use is `DataAvailable` - you already know there is data from the `Read`  attempt

Comment: DataAvailable allows you do see whether there is - guess what, data available. It is part of the "i do not need to process sockets for which there is no data yet instead of waiting". Check whether there is data, then read what data is there. How else can you sensible write a server having like 30k open connections?

Comment: So this property is probably only really useful to servers, not clients then. A server can expect a client to re-connect (and notice this is a dupe of an existing connection) but a client waiting on a server is responsible to check the socket is OK because the server is not going to to re-connect.

Comment: Not really. See, if you READ DATA there is no guarantee you get ALL data - so IF you read, you read in a loop as long as DataAvailable = true. Then you wait for the next data.